# How open an external application and simulate file on side?

Tags: winapi

I want to open an external program to my project. okay. The folder it is this:

> ... 
>   **Externalapp.exe**

But for the **Externalapp.exe** work, its need a file called **key.lua** that can not be visible to the user *(for security reasons)*.

So I thought **I'd include this file in the dynamically call** from my **Externalapp.exe** for him to think that the **key.lua** is on your side.

Is it possible?

Comment: Does externalapp.exe have an interface that allows you to specify the "key.lua" file? Perhaps the command line options?

Comment: He has not. The key.lua really need be by your side, in the same folder. Externalapp.exe is a console program without interface.

Comment: I want the externalapp.exe think that there is a file called key.lua in the same folder it. And so he can also read the contents of key.lua.

Comment: And If the externalapp.exe not find the key.lua in the same folder it gives error.

Comment: You security is insecure

Comment: But is this possible? Because unfortunately, it seems the only solution!

Comment: Well, maybe temporarily place a link to lua.key (i.e. a *.Lnk file) in ExternalApp's folder before you call it and delete it immediately after it has run?

Comment: What if I create the key.lua file and block for copying and removal? Is it possible?

Comment: How are you going to create the file and stop the user copying it? You really need to try and understand how computer security works. Until you have a solid grounding in that you are just wasting your time. You won't make anything secure. Only with a deep understanding can you be secure. If your program can read the file, so can the user. It's his machine after all.

Comment: I don't quite understand what your question is asking (not like I would know how to solve it...). Are you trying to create a super-hidden key.lua file that your program relies on to run? Or are you trying to fake a key.lua file for some other program? And why are you using a Lua script for security?! (I'm no expert but that doesn't sound smart... correct me if I am wrong.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First a few words about security:**

As others have already mentioned in comments storing any data regarding the security in LUA files is terrible idea. Why? LUA files are textual files so any user can see the contents of it. Now you can try hiding this file by putting it into some not so obvious folder but there is still risk that the user may stumble upon it somehow.

If you can change your ExternalApp athleast give it the ability to load the encrypted LUA file and encrypt your LUA file acordingly.

**And now to the posible answer to your question:**

It might be posible to convince your ExternalApp to load LUA file that is not in same directory as the ExternalApp is by setting the working directoy to be different from your ExternalApp location.

Here is a Delphi code example that uses both ShellExecute and ShellExecuteEx API calls.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var SEInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
    ExitCode: DWORD;
begin
  //Using ShellExecute
  ShellExecute(Handle,'open','C:\ExternalApp.exe',nil,'D:\',SW_SHOWNORMAL);

  //Using ShellExecuteEx
  FillChar(SEInfo, SizeOf(SEInfo), 0);
  SEInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
  SEInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  SEInfo.Wnd := Application.Handle;
  SEInfo.lpFile := PChar('C:\ExternalApp.exe');
  SEInfo.lpDirectory := PCHAR('D:\');
  SEInfo.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  if ShellExecuteEx(@SEInfo) then
  begin
    repeat
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      GetExitCodeProcess(SEInfo.hProcess, ExitCode) ;
    until (ExitCode <> STILL_ACTIVE) or Application.Terminated;
    ShowMessage('External application terminated') ;
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('Error starting External application!') ;
end;
```

NOTE: This will only work if your ExternalApp is trying to find the LUA file by using GetCurrentDirectory or GetWorkDirectory cals to get the path location of LUA file.
But it will not work if your ExternalApp is getting this path by extracting path location of its executable.

Comment: Why did you choose to use that busy loop? Why did you leak the handle? You realise that the asker is going to use this code? And that the asker thinks their app is now secure.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan About the busy loop: To be honest I haven't used ShellExecuteEx till today so that part of code is simply copied from one of quicx examples of how to use ShellExecuteEx. Aparently that examle isn't best to use. As for the leaking handle: Where do I leak handle? As for OP thinking that this code would make his app secure. If he also reads the first part of my answer he should understand that using LUA files to store any data regarding security poses a risk wheter you hide them from user or not. Now if OP is to lazy to read that or disregard that then that is his problem.

Comment: You'd know about the handle leak if you read the docs. Anyway, CreateProcess is the right api. There's no sense in posting bad code. There's enough around without adding more.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have read the docs for SehllExecuteEx twice now but I still fail to see where I leak that handle.

Comment: You've got a handle. You don't close it. Therefore you've leaked it.

Comment: David is referring to the process handle kept open by using SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS. You have to close that handle when you are done using it.